# No puedo imprimir los atributos de un componente blade en Larave 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Este problema es muy fácil pero no lo he podido resolver. Tengo un componente de clase blade **BalanceCard.php** el cual recibe un atributo llamado **total-utility** y tal atributo viene sin formato y deberia imprimirse con formato después de pasar por el constructor, sin embargo no lo hace.

De tal forma que si **total-utility** es igual a **1000** deberia imprimirse como **1.000**

Este es el código de **BalanceCard.php**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\View\Components\general;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class BalanceCard extends Component
{
    public float $totalUtility;

    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(float $totalUtility)
    {
        $this->totalUtility = (float)number_format($totalUtility, 2, thousands_separator: '.');
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Closure|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.general.balance-card');
    }
}
```

Esta es la vista de **BalanceCArd.php**

```
<div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px;">
    <div class="row g-0">
        <div class="col-md-6 d-flex align-items-center">
            <div class="text-center">
                <h1>Utilidad total</h1>
                 ***AQUI ESTA LO IMPORTANTE****
                <h3>{{$totalUtility}}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div>
                    <h4>Ventas totales</h4>
                    <h3>5.000</h3>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h4>Gastos totales</h4>
                    <h3>50.000</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y asi lo llamo dentro de la vista

```
<x-general.balance-card :total-utility="1000"></x-general.balance-card>
```

He intentado cambiar el valor de **total-utility** desde el constructor, para ver si hace efecto y me he dado de cuenta de que blade siempre imprime el valor que se le pasa como atributo HTML, es como si no pasara por el constructor, como pueden ver, esto es lo que he intentado y sin embargo sigue imprimiendo **1000** sin formato.

```
public function __construct(float $totalUtility)
    {
        $this->totalUtility = 1562262.00;
    }
```

Comment: tengo el mismo problema que este sujeto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66790126/cannot-access-blade-component-variables-inside-the-view

Comment: cuando creo el componente dentro de una carpeta como balance/BalanceCard no funciona pero si solo lo creo como artisan make:component BalanceCard si funciona